# Pushing data to object/array for later comparison

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to **store strings** in a **object/array for later comparison**. I have no idea if my approach is correct.

**The idea:**
I'll be using the data to compare if there's been changes in the HTML where the strings are from. If there are changes the script is gonna send a notification with information on what changes there is.


So I have a function that needs to push data into either an object or an array. I need to store the data for later use, where I need to compare if there's any changes. It's specifically a scheme of classes.


**An example of what the object/array is gonna look after the data is injected:**

```
    obj = 
    {
      "mon": { 
              0:{date:date, info:info, class:class}
              1:{date:date, info:info, class:class}
              2:{date:date, info:info, class:class}
             },
      "tue": {...},
      "...":
    }
```

And so on... So the object/array is gonna contain data for every class, for every day.
I need to be able to compare the stored obj.mon.0 with the new obj.mon.0, as an example.

**So my question is:**

What's the best approach, in an object as above, or in a array?
How do I go about storing information in the object/array for every class, on every day?
And is this even the easiest approach for this context?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: If the index (0, 1, 2, ...) has no special meaning of its own you should use an array.

Comment: It does have a meaning. Because I need to be able to separate between classes for each day.

Comment: So far it sounds just like an index in an array, which doesn't have a meaning of its own.

Comment: Oh, yeah that sounds right. So it would be like: "mon": [{...}], [{...}] correct?

Comment: "mon": [{...}, {...}, {...}], "tue": [{...}]

Comment: Perfect. And then I'd be using .push() to store the data, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array is probably the best to choose here.

and you can keep the date, info and class as object.

Please share your suggestions too.